# Граница из звездечек

Tags: javascript

Есть массив А вокруг элементов которого с  помощью звездечек нужно строить границу.
Например в случае 
А  = ["abc", "ded"];
получится  массив  ["*****", "* abc* ", "* ded* ", "*****"];
Нужно написать функцию которая для введенного массива построит его границу из звездечек и вернет полученный массив.

```
function addAsterisks(A) {
    for (x of A) {
        return '*' + x + '*';
    }
}
console.log(addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"]));
// Должен выводится ["*****", "*abc*", "*ded*", "*****"]
console.log(addAsterisks(["a"]));
// Должен выводится ["***", "*a*", "***"]
console.log(addAsterisks(["aa", "**", "zz"]));
// Должен выводится ["****", "*aa*", "****", "*zz*", "****"]
console.log(addAsterisks(["abcde", "fghij", "klmno", "pqrst", "uvwxy"]));
// Должен выводится ["*******", "*abcde*", "*fghij*", "*klmno*","*pqrst*","*uvwxy*","*******"]
```

Помогите пожолуйста решить задачу

Comment: А что должно вывестись для `["a", "bc", "def"]`?

Answer (score 6):

```js
    function addAsterisks(A) {
        let Lenght = A.length;
        let num = A[0].split('');
        let num1 = num.length;
        for(let i=0;i<Lenght; i++){
            A[i] = "*"+A[i]+"*";
        }
        A.push('*'.repeat(num1+2));
        A.unshift('*'.repeat(num1+2));
        return A;
    }
    console.log(addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"]));
    // Должен выводится ["*****", "*abc*", "*ded*", "*****"]
    console.log(addAsterisks(["a"]));
    // Должен выводится ["***", "*a*", "***"]
    console.log(addAsterisks(["aa", "**", "zz"]));
    // Должен выводится ["****", "*aa*", "****", "*zz*", "****"]
    console.log(addAsterisks(["abcde", "fghij", "klmno", "pqrst", "uvwxy"]));
```

Comment: Классно, но это не помощь. Это парнишка понял ещё раз, что за него всё сделают ботаны )))

Comment: @AlexSazonov Вы правы. Но я заметил последнее время вот такую некую тенденцию. Когда человек задаёт свой первый вопрос - ему можно помочь, но объяснить, что ему надо сначала самому пытаться сделать, чтобы ему помогли, как корректно сделали Вы. А второй и далее разы тут уж извините. )

Comment: @Denis640Kb: вот, не совсем согласен. Люди разучились думать, мало читают, не могут понятно изложить мысль. А ведь правильно заданный вопрос - это половина ответа. Сколько раз я отказывался задать вопрос, находя ответ в процессе формулировки вопроса. Э-эх...

Comment: @UModel, Тут я с Вами тоже согласен, но есть одна вещь, которую мы тоже обсуждали. Скоро создам вопрос на мете - было бы интересно услышать и Ваш ответ. О том, что очень многим новичкам в резкой форме сразу отказывают. Из-за чего они никогда больше не возвращаются на сайт.  Что обидно, потому что сообщество растёт не так быстро, как возможно. По-этому я как-то так для себя решил, что первый вопрос авансом ))) Чтобы было желание возвращаться в сообщество.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addAsterisks(A) {
    var n_a = ['']
    for (x of A) {
        n_a.push('*' + x + '*');
    }
    var star_str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < n_a[1].length; i++) {
        star_str += '*';
    }
    n_a.push(star_str);
    n_a[0] = star_str;
    return n_a;
}

console.log(addAsterisks(["abc", "ded"]));
// Должен выводится ["*****", "*abc*", "*ded*", "*****"]
console.log(addAsterisks(["a"]));
// Должен выводится ["***", "*a*", "***"]
console.log(addAsterisks(["aa", "**", "zz"]));
// Должен выводится ["****", "*aa*", "****", "*zz*", "****"]
console.log(addAsterisks(["abcde", "fghij", "klmno", "pqrst", "uvwxy"]));
```